# Unable to access pub dev site

Tags: dart, flutter-dependencies

does any experiencing **pub.dev** site error down in Nigeria,? and it's affecting my HTTP host availability.

have try sorting out the answer on various platforms, which proves to be abortive.

Answer (score 1):

in Nigeria people have found that their access depends on their Internet Service Provider (ISP).
i'm facing the same issue in Angola
this is something that flutter team or pub.dev team can't do too much

to resolve

you can use a VPN

or [follow the steps to use flutter in china](https://docs.flutter.dev/community/china)

By doing this you'll be getting the packages from a Mirror site that our providers didn't block

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issues for days until i downloaded hotspot shield.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).