# Got socket error trying to find package logger at https://pub.dartlang.org

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

Whenever I tried using flutter commands such as flutter pub get/add/upgrade/outdated after upgrading my flutter sdk manually to the latest version available, I would always get the **socket error** message and this continued until I found a solution for it recently.

I veified if my flutter was inserted in the user environment correctly which it was and also checked if git was applied correctly but none of those where the issue.

**So I tried these few steps: under system variable by creating a new system path for each of these**

1. Open environment variable settings
2. Create a new variable path with the name: PUB_HOSTED_URL and its value: https://pub.flutter-io.cn
3. Create a new variable path with the name: FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL and its value: https://storage.flutter-io.cn

and thats it, it worked.
Hopefully this helps

Comment: where are you located on??

Comment: Do you mean where am I located?
Im located at Boksburg under Johannesburg. Why do you ask?

Comment: for some reason,here in africa we got  this problem often
i'm in Angola , some people in  Nigeria and Ghana report this also.
i think this happens because ower internet providers are partners of Chinese Companies,

related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72917297/unable-to-access-pub-dev-site/77904985#77904985

Comment: I see.
Thank you for this information, it totally makes sence. I am able to view and download sdk's as well.